# How to do code reviews to Android applications in github?

Tags: android, android-studio, github-codereviews

As a team member, we work on creating an Android app with Github. We use PR's and code reviews. We also use Android Studio for development,

It's hard to do code reviews to the layouts without actually seeing them. I was wondering if there is some tool or method to share an instance of application in order to see changes?

Answer (score 0):

Each member could simply clone the PR branch and perform the QA locally, I suppose.

Comment: That's the hard way. In a project I worked on web development, we had to just share instance of the web with a url and that's it. I was wondering if there is something similiar with Android.

Comment: I'm a mobile developer myself and that's the reality of things, web deployment is much easier and quicker. You could set up a GitHub action to build and upload an APK to Google Play Console on every PR. Then you could simply create a test and invite your coworkers.